# Tkinter: Problem uploading image and displaying it

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

I'm working on a program that acts as a uploader of items, such as merchandise, and allows it to be edited, and also removed. At the moment, I'm only working on the "add" button. What I'm trying to do (near the bottom) is allow for the user to upload an image via their computer/file explorer, and have it display in a little spot in the GUI. Here is my code for just the main section:

```
class AddWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.title('Add new item')

        #Creates all of the "add" buttons windows variables
        #(centers it, doesn't let it be resizeable, etc.)
        window_width = 500
        window_height = 500
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
        center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
        self.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        #Defines all the padding for labels/entrys
        options1 = {'ipadx': 20, 'ipady': 20, 'padx': 10, 'pady': 5}
        options2 = {'ipadx': 35, 'ipady': 5, 'padx': 10, 'pady': 5}
        options3 = {'ipadx': 35, 'ipady': 30, 'padx': 10, 'pady': 5} #Not currently used
        options4 = {'ipadx': 20, 'ipady': 20, 'padx': 10, 'pady': 25}
        options5 = {'ipadx': 35, 'ipady': 5, 'padx': 10, 'pady': 5}

        #Creates the "name" label area
        name = StringVar()
        name_label = Label(self, text='Name:')
        name_label.pack(anchor=NW, **options1)
        name_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=name)
        name_entry.pack(anchor=NW, **options2)

        #Creates the "description" label area
        description = StringVar()
        description_label = Label(self, text='Description:')
        description_label.pack(anchor=NW, **options1)
        description_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=description)
        description_entry.pack(anchor=NW, **options2)

        #Creates the "currency" label area
        currency = StringVar()
        currency_label = Label(self, text='Price:')
        currency_label.pack(anchor=NW, **options1)
        currency_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=currency)
        currency_entry.pack(anchor=NW, **options2)

        #Creates the "image" area
        image_button1 = Button(self, text='Upload picture...', command=self.fileDialog)
        image_button1.pack(anchor=E, **options5)

        #Creates the "save" button
        save_button = Button(self, text='Save and Create', command=save_button_clicked)
        save_button.pack(anchor=S, **options4)

#The Main Issue
    def fileDialog(self): 
        #Allows for upload of a file
        global img
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("jpeg", "*.jpg"), ("png", "*.png")))
        img=Image.open(filename)
        #Resizes the file (not finalized)
        img_resized=img.resize((400,200))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)
        #Displays the image
        image_button2 = Button(AddWindow, image=img)
        image_button2.pack(anchor=NE)
```

[Here is a picture of what it looks like as well (the picture should display above "Upload picture..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAJjO.jpg)

The main issue that comes out is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nate1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nate1\Downloads\MerchandiseHub.py", line 76, in fileDialog
    image_button2 = Button(AddWindow, image=img)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Nate1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 582, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::button", kw)
  File "C:\Users\Nate1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 527, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\Nate1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2622, in __init__
    self._setup(master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Nate1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2591, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
              ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'AddWindow' has no attribute 'tk'
```

The big problem is that the chosen image doesn't even display, and just comes out with an error.

With this, one solution I've tried is to make a tk.frame sort of thing in the AddWindow section, but it would just create a whole new window, and it also seems like I'd have to replace a lot of variables/strings/etc. with tk.xxxx, which doesn't seem very optimal (although, if I must do it, I will).

I've also looked in previous answers on this site, but they're all too old, among other websites for a few hours now. Any idea for a solution on this? This is working towards my final project in my Python class, and don't have all too much time left.

Comment: You're trying to pass a widget class (`AddWindow`) as the first argument to `Button(...)`, but the first argument must be an _instance_ of a widget class.